# Quando devemos permitir que uma coluna de uma tabela de um banco de dados aceite NULL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tipagem, null

Esta é uma pergunta conceitual que sempre gera confusão na hora de decidir se uma coluna deve ou não aceitar [NULL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90363/101).

Há uma [corrente que considera o uso do NULL um erro](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=406_pJtiJ6sC) e que sempre deveria ser feito uma organização no banco de dados, normalmente aplicando [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101), evitando assim qualquer uso de valores NULL.

Tenho uma dúvida especial com colunas do tipo `character` (em qualquer de suas variantes) onde existe uma forma de representar que não há qualquer informação, mantendo a coluna em estado vazio. Mas esse valor pode não ser suficiente para indicar o que se quer com a coluna.

Já obtive alguma [resposta no Stack Exchange do ponto de vista do DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59/when-to-use-null-and-when-to-use-an-empty-string). Mas além das respostas não terem me satisfeito completamente, tinham um viés do administrador e não do desenvolvedor, e eu também acabei me restringindo a um tipo de campo e ficou a dúvida se o mesmo comportamento valeria para outros tipos de colunas que possam ou não ter um valor natural que possa representar a ausência de valor. Você pode usar o valor 0 ou negativo em alguns campos, definindo o uso do valor como ausência de valor relevante.

Cada sistema de banco de dados trata NULL de um jeito diferente e é muito difícil transferir um modelo criado em um banco para outro com semântica diferente. Quando você cria sua própria semântica, isso fica mais fácil.

Então, existem cenários em que o NULL é realmente benéfico e seu uso traz vantagens que compensem os problemas que o seu uso pode carregar?

Comment: O [padrão SQL-ISO tem NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Null_and_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29), a função `COALESCE()` e o operador "IS NULL"... **É um estado**, com significado de "valor não informado" ou "não existente", e *não um valor*.  O NULL é largamente utilizado, não faz sentido questionar a sua utilidade. Existe é uma pequena briga de conceitos e formas de modelagem que pode substituir o uso do NULL ISO. Acho que a pergunta/respostas está enfatizando uma dicotomia (**"NULL é do bem ou é do mal?"**) que não existe, e desvia a discussão objetiva sobre os conceitos de modelagem.

Comment: Que tal aproveitar o entusiasmo para contribuirmos com a pobre [Wikipedia Português nesse tipo de discussão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))?  Pode-se aproveitar o amplo panorama levantado pelo [artigo em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)), que já tem nas respostas abaixo uma ótima tradução e explanação didática de parte dos tópicos(!)

Comment: Tem casos que é físico , você NÃO TEM a informação , simples assim , ela não impende uma operação , você engole o NULL. ,,, Sua Compra não foi aceita pois o sr(a) não informou sua cor favorita ... Outro dia um cara que cuida da TI de uma loja feminina , contou um caso : quase todas as clientes tinham 21 (2021) anos pois informavam só o dia e mês de nascimento , não venderia para a senhora então ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Um pouco de história

A questão sobre o uso de `null` é discutido por desenvolvedores de diversas plataformas. Já ouvi muito isso em Java também.

Certa ocasião, conversando com um colega após um `NullPointerException` ter estourado em produção, ele estava argumentando que `null` não deveria existir, que alguém, não sei onde, estava tentando remover o `null` do Java, etc. Para linguagens orientadas a objetos, algumas pessoas sugerem o uso de um *design pattern* (padrão de projeto) chamado *Null Object* (Objeto Nulo).

Além disso, já peguei alguns problemas em várias *procedures* e *queries* decorrentes do não tratamento de campos `null`, principalmente com valores nulos em expressões booleanas, resultando em comportamentos imprevistos (veja a "tabela" que o @mgibsonbr postou em sua resposta).

Um histórico interessante sobre a controvérsia do `null` encontra-se na [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)<sup>[em Inglês]</sup>.

## Um caso onde o *não* uso de `null` gera problemas

Imagine uma tabela de pacientes de um sistema para consultórios médicos, cujo campo `idade` é `unsigned integer not null`. Analisemos o seguinte código em PHP:

```php
$idade = empty($campo_idade) ? 0 : intval($campo_idade);
if (!$idade) throw new Exception('A idade deve ser preenchida.');
insere_cliente(..., $idade, ...);
```

O código acima tenta verificar se o campo idade tem um valor que é considerado verdadeiro (`true`) para o PHP antes de inserir no banco de dados. Isso funciona? Sim, desde que o consultório não atenda bebês com menos de 1 ano de idade.

Agora vamos supor que vendemos o sistema para uma clínica de pediatria. O que faremos agora que o valor `0` (zero) deve ser válido? Apenas removemos a validação (`if`), já que o banco de dados está "protegido" contra valores nulos e negativos.

Então começamos a receber várias reclamações de que determinados pacientes estão aparecendo com idade zero. Identificamos que as secretárias frequentemente esquecem de preencher a idade e o cadastro é incluído com idade zero por padrão. Isso é fácil de resolver, basta impedir que o cadastro seja feito se o campo estiver vazio, não é?

Mas vamos supor ainda que algumas das clínicas clientes possuem pronto-socorro e algumas vezes é necessário fazer o cadastro de um paciente sem saber sua idade exata. Os gerentes das clínicas precisam saber quais cadastros *não* possuem a idade preenchida para colher essa informação posteriormente. E agora? Agora falta um *valor* para dizermos que *não há valor* e sabemos que zero não é uma opção.

## O que `null` significa para você?

Um valor nulo faz muito sentido quando faz parte da regra de negócio tratar um valor *não informado* ou *não existente*.

A verdade é que usar outros valores, como números negativos ou constantes textuais, para representar valores não existentes é uma mistura de conceitos e gera vários problemas. Será que, na falta de sal, alguém deveria colocar açúcar no saleiro para evitar a decepção de um convidado ao encontrar o recipiente vazio?

O padrão de projeto *Null Object*, por exemplo, pode evitar uma exceção em linguagens OO, mas se o valor não for devidamente tratado, poderá gerar comportamentos muito estranhos. Imagine um usuário fazendo uma consulta e a tela abrindo com todos os campos vazios porque o registro consultado não foi encontrado e um *null object* foi retornado e "apresentado" na interface do sistema.

## Alguns tratamentos para `null` em SQL

Cada linguagem de programação tem seus métodos para tratamento de nulos, mas não vou entrar nessa questão aqui.

Os SGBDRs podem apresentar comportamentos diferentes quanto ao valor `null`, mas em minha experiência, basta seguir algumas boas práticas de desenvolvimento podem evitar esses problemas. Uma delas é não usar apenas o operador `=`, mas também o `IS NULL` ou `IS NOT NULL` ao pesquisar colunas que podem ser nulas, por exemplo:

```sql
select * from tabela where (nome is null or nome = '')
```

Outro exemplo, segundo o caso delineado no tópico anterior, que retorna pacientes sem idade preenchida:

```sql
select * from paciente where idade is null
```

A mesma lógica vale para qualquer tipo de campo ou variável. Exemplo em Transact-SQL:

```sql
create procedure atualiza_paciente_sem_idade(
    @id int, 
    @nova_idade int
) 
as 

declare @idade_atual int
set @idade_atual = (select idade from paciente where id = @id)
if @idade_atual is null
begin
    update paciente set idade = @nova_idade where id = @id
    insert into log (...)
end
```

Além disso, é importante usar a rotina adequada para tratar campos nulos antes de tentar manipular os dados. Exemplo no SQL Server:

```sql
select upper(isnull(campo_possivelmente_nulo, '')) from tabela
```

Infelizmente, cada sistema de banco de dados parece ter implementado uma solução própria para retornar um valor *default* no caso de um `null`. Oracle usa `NVL`, Microsoft SQL Server e Access usam `ISNULL`, MySQL usa `IFNULL` e PostgreSQL não tem uma função equivalente. Veja alguns exemplos [neste link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp).

Porém, uma alternativa que parece funcionar em todos os SGBDRs citados é o `COALESCE`. Esta função retorna o primeiro valor não nulo de uma lista de valores. Por exemplo:

```sql
select coalesce(campo_possivelmente_nulo1, 'valor inexistente') from tabela
```

O efeito do comando acima é o mesmo do anterior.

Uma outra abordagem é criar uma função personalizada para tratar isso. Por exemplo, criar uma função `ISNULL` no Oracle com a mesma implementação do `NVL` já existente. Entretanto, como existem diversas outras divergências entre as implementações SQL, creio não valer a penas essa abordagem. Para sistemas com suporte a vários tipos de bancos de dados, dou preferência para abstração provida por um framework [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (Mapeamento Objeto-Relacional).

Outra situação a ter nossa atenção é quando *joins* são necessários. Mas não é nada muito complicado. Basta conhecer diferença e saber quando usar `INNER JOIN` e `OUTER JOIN`. Saber sobre `LEFT JOIN` e `RIGHT JOIN` também ajuda.

É muito comum perguntas na internet como: "minha consulta não lista uma clínica quando não há pacientes cadastrados, o que pode ser?"

Isso ocorre porque foi usado `INNER JOIN` no lugar de `OUTER JOIN`.

Vejamos um exemplo:

```sql
select clinica.id, avg(paciente.idade) as average
from clinica
join paciente on paciente.id_clinica = clinica.id
group by clinica.id
```

A consulta acima pretende calcular a média de idade dos pacientes de uma clínica. O problema é que somente serão listadas clínicas que possuem pelo menos um paciente.

Vamos mudar um pouco essa query:

```sql
select clinica.id, avg(paciente.idade) as average
from clinica
left outer join paciente on paciente.id_clinica = clinica.id
group by clinica.id
```

Agora, com o `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, clínica sem pacientes retornarão uma média nula. Note que nesse caso não queremos que a média seja `0` (zero) quando não há pacientes, pois se a clínica atendesse apenas a recém-nascidos a média seria efetivamente *zero anos de idade*!

Se alguém quiser testar essas queries, pode usar [este SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/166fe/1).

## Considerações

A questão principal é que, do ponto de vista do usuário, um erro ou comportamento estranho causado por `null` é tão ruim quando um erro, comportamento estranho ou limitação devido ao *não* uso de `null`.

Um engodo muito grande que está por detrás de alguns argumentos contra o `null` é: se não houvessem `null`s ocorreriam menos erros de execução. Na verdade, erros ocorrem porque desenvolvedores em geral não criam código efetivamente "seguro", isto é, tratando os valores de entrada adequadamente. Então alguns querem contornar o problema da qualidade do código removendo valores que fazem o código falhar.

Validar qualquer *input*, incluindo entrada do usuário e leituras de arquivos e banco de dados, é  (e sempre será) boa prática de programação. O programador "preguiçoso" é que pensa: "minha rotina só lançou uma exceção não esperada porque **fulano** enviou o valor `XPTO`".

Enfim, campos nulos, que poderia chamar de *opcionais*, são uma necessidade em vários tipos de situação. O esforço de limitar seu uso não melhora efetivamente a qualidade dos sistemas. Se os desenvolvedores não criarem uma lógica adequada para as rotinas do sistemas, de nada adianta usar nulos ou valores para simular campos vazios.

E se, por uma mudança nas regras de negócio, um campo passar a ser *nullable*? *Bugs* vão surgir por toda parte?

Comment: Na faculdade tive discussões ferrenhas com o professor de BD - eu sempre defendi o uso de NULL, shortnames e nome de tabelas case sensite. Que por default é uma afronta aos fan boys do Oracle, que era o caso dele - 1:30 para cada aula era pouco pra tanta discussão. Mas queria ter conhecido esse caso da clinica/pronto-socorro para dar de exemplo de uso.

Comment: Concordo. O *NULL* é meu amigo para expressar ausência de valor. Usar códigos (`0`, `""`, `-1`...) é só uma maneira confusa de dizer a mesma coisa. Tentar evitar erros no sistema tirando o *NULL* é parecido com eliminar bug usando *catch* mudo. O pattern NullObject, por sua vez, é bem restrito. Ele já tem um defeito de nascença que é ter que saber o que o consumidor vai fazer com ele.

Answer (score 14):

### Teoria

É preciso ter muito cuidado ao utilizar `NULL` pois ele opera segundo a [**lógica ternária**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_tern%C3%A1ria). Ou seja, estritamente falando, a [semântica do `NULL`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_tern%C3%A1ria#Aplica.C3.A7.C3.B5es_de_bancos_de_dados) não é "ausência de valor", e sim "valor **desconhecido**". Veja algumas tabelas da verdade para a lógica ternária:

```
    A        |  não A
-------------+--------------
Verdadeiro   |  Falso
Falso        |  Verdadeiro
Desconhecido |  Desconhecido

A e B        |                 B
      A      | Verdadeiro    Falso  Desconhecido
-------------+----------------------------------
Verdadeiro   | Verdadeiro    Falso  Desconhecido
Falso        | Falso         Falso  Falso
Desconhecido | Desconhecido  Falso  Desconhecido

A ou B       |                 B
      A      | Verdadeiro  Falso         Desconhecido
-------------+----------------------------------
Verdadeiro   | Verdadeiro  Verdadeiro    Verdadeiro
Falso        | Verdadeiro  Falso         Desconhecido
Desconhecido | Verdadeiro  Desconhecido  Desconhecido
```

Além de comparações booleanas, outros tipos de operação também têm resultados "surpreendentes" quando se admite o `NULL`. Por exemplo, a seguinte expressão:

```sql
Cidade = 'Porto Alegre' OR Balanco < 0.0
```

Vai retornar `TRUE` se a cidade for "Porto Alegre" ou o balanço tiver um valor negativo, `FALSE` se a cidade for **definida** e diferente de "Porto Alegre" e o balanço for **definido** e maior ou igual a zero. Caso contrário, retornará `UNKNOWN`.

A expressão `NULL = NULL` - contrário ao senso comum - não retornará `TRUE`, mas sim `UNKNOWN`.

### Prática

Em geral, a linguagem que **consome** os resultados de uma consulta SQL não segue a lógica ternária. Para ela, verdadeiro é verdadeiro e qualquer outra coisa é falso. Isso permite que se use o `NULL` em uma variedade de situações sem acarretar em qualquer problema. Mas os *pitfalls* permanecem: como a comparação com `NULL` mencionada acima. É preciso ter isso em mente ao se decidir trabalhar com `NULL`.

### Casos de Uso

Pessoalmente, não considero boa prática usar colunas textuais *nullable*, pois:

1. se for um campo aberto, uma string vazia (ou mesmo uma só com espaços em branco) é semanticamente equivalente à ausência de informação (i.e. para um humano, não faz diferença);
2. se for um campo "escolha" (i.e. o tipo da coluna é texto, mas existe um conjunto finito de strings que são aceitas), nada impede que se crie uma entrada adicional para "não informado", "desconhecido", "não aplicável", etc;
3. se se tratar de uma entidade mais complexa (que pode ou não estar ausente), o ideal seria criar uma nova tabela para representá-la (substituindo o campo textual por uma chave estrangeira).

Quanto ao uso de `NULL` para outros tipos de dados simples (números, datas), não vejo problemas: às vezes é interessante sim ter um valor que represente "dado ausente" - e escolher um valor qualquer do próprio domínio me parece estranho. Porém, não tenho nenhum argumento objetivo nem contra nem a favor...

Em chaves estrangeiras, o `NULL` é uma maneira conveniente de se representar "valor faltando" ou "não aplicável": o uso de uma linha em especial para representar esse valor obrigaria o programador a testar uma condição adicional a cada query executada (i.e. testar se essa linha é a "linha especial"). Isso não é problema se você **já faz esse tipo de teste rotineiramente** (por exemplo, se seu sistema não **exclui** linhas, mas as **marca como excluídas**), mas no geral acarreta em mais complexidade e mais uma fonte de erro (esquecer de testar por esse valor especial). Isso é mais importante em agregações. O comportamento padrão do `NULL` segundo a lógica ternária é "próximo o suficiente" do que o programador espera intuitivamente, de modo que as *queries* se mantém mais simples.

Um caso particular onde a diferença entre usar ou não usar o `NULL` é um pouco mais significativa são as **tabelas que se auto-referenciam**; uma chave estrangeira não *nullable* combinada com uma chave primária que se auto-incrementa exigiria uma "gambiarra" para se adicionar a primeira linha pelo menos (i.e. torne a coluna *nullable*, adicione a linha "vazia", atribua a chave primária para o "self", torne a coluna não *nullable*). Há também o potencial de um loop infinito caso se tente "seguir" as referências até a origem (se o programador se esquecer de testar a auto-referência), mas na prática se você está fazendo isso sua modelagem está aquém do ideal (uma [*closure table*](http://technobytz.com/closure_table_store_hierarchical_data.html) seria mais apropriada nesse caso - seja sua estrutura em forma de árvore ou não). Porém, nada do que foi descrito aqui é não contornável...

### Conclusão

Não conheço argumentos fortes, nem casos de uso específicos, que defendam o uso do `NULL`. Se é importante que seu banco de dados seja **portável** e/ou o uso do `NULL` está causando problemas em seu SGBD atual, então é *viável* eliminar seu uso em qualquer situação prática. Caso contrário, utilizá-lo torna as *queries* um tanto mais simples e reduz a possibilidade de certos erros (ainda que introduza a possibilidade de outros).

Comment: Lembretes: 1) o NULL é estado, não é valor, por isso a falsa "surpresa". Algebricamente o NULL é "contaminante", tal como *Infinite* ou *NotNumber*. 2) a chamada *"NOT NULL constraint"*, prevista em qualquer versão de SQL, e fundamental em qualquer modelagem, permite justamente trazer de volta para *boolean* o tipo "boolean ternário".

Comment: Esta é uma idéia nova pra mim. Eu vejo NULL como **ausência de valor** e não como valor desconhecido. O resultado de `NULL == 0` é `DESCONHECIDO` não porque a primeira variável é desconhecida mas sim porque é impossível comparar um valor com uma ausência de valor - tal qual na natureza: é impossível saber se uma estrela é mais brilhante que outra ou se um jacaré é tão pesado quanto outro se não houver outra estrela e outro jacaré para comparação. Acho que o *NULL* é ótimo para expressar ausência de valor e eu o utilizo amplamente com este fim tanto no código quanto no banco de dados.

Comment: @Caffé O valor nulo tal como usado em linguagens de programação realmente tem essa semântica, de ausência de valor. Mas de acordo com as referências que eu indiquei (há outras, mas não me recordo agora) no contexto de um banco de dados relacional a semântica adotada é de fato a lógica ternária. Isso não saiu da minha cabeça, garanto... :P Aliás, você está correto em afirmar que `NULL == 0` é desconhecido, mas esse "desconhecido" acaba sendo representado por... `NULL`! ;) P.S. Não vejo problema algum em - **em uma tabela** - usar `NULL` como ausência de valor. Faço isso também.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Eu não diria que `desconhecido` é representado por `NULL`. Eu diria que se eu tentar utilizar o resultado daquela comparação, este resultado será convertido em ausência de valor, NULL, o que é uma convenção já que representar `DESCONHECIDO` acrescenta mais complexidade que simplicidade. Mas eu entendi seu ponto e apreciei ler sua resposta.

Answer (score 12):

Não a título de resposta completa, mas sim de contribuição com o assunto:

Um  possível uso do `Null` é diferenciar valores em que numérico zero e string vazia tenham significados diferentes de campos com informação faltando. Um exemplo simplificado, só para esclarecer:

Você tem uma aplicação de cadastro, e um dos campos é o fiador do contrato. Na sua UI você tem campos que diferenciam informação fornecida ou faltando. O `Null` num caso desses indicaria que falta preencher esta informação (não sabemos se há um fiador ou não, falta o usuário indicar claramente através da UI), enquanto a string vazia indicaria que é sabido que o contrato não tem fiador. Neste segundo caso, foi fornecida a informação pelo usuário do sistema, que "por acaso" é uma string vazia.

---

Como você já notou, há também as aplicações de uso específico, dependendo do tipo de DB utilizado, como no MySQL:

Um dos usos possíveis do `Null` é suprir a falta de um campo do tipo "bit". A motivação para quem é adepto dessa técnica é a seguinte:

Para você armazenar um mero sim ou não em um numérico, por menor que seja, você usa 8 bits. Por sua vez, se voce cria um campo caractere de comprimento zero, mas que aceita `Null`, terá na prática um bit (o do `Null`) ocupado para dizer se é uma string vazia ou um nulo.

Entretanto, na prática, com o espaço de armazenagem geralmente não sendo o gargalo das atuais aplicações, não consigo ver se realmente é vantajosa a economia de espaço em troca da lógica adicional para implementar esta economia (inclusive pelo fato de que pra economizar espaço, você precisaria ter vários campos `Null` em uso, pois de qualquer forma o *padding* do bitfield de `Null`s vai ser de 8 bits).

Answer (score 7):

Eu geralmente utilizo `NULL` em uma coluna, quando preciso utilizar uma FK em em algumas situações, e em outras, não. Exemplo: Tenho uma tabela chamada `evento`, que registra eventos ocorridos no sistema. Certos registros de `evento` são relacionados com um registro da tabela `tarefa`, através de uma chave estrangeira que guarda o ID do registro da tabela estrangeira.
Em certas ocasiões, não há uma tarefa relacionada ao evento, e em outras, há. Se não houver, eu coloco `NULL`. Não daria para colocar outro valor, porque não existe ID 0, e a chave estrangeira não me permite inserir o registro, e qualquer outro valor numérico superior a 0, estaria relacionando com um registro.

Com o campo de `evento` em `NULL`, eu posso fazer `LEFT JOIN` por exemplo, trazendo os dados de `tarefa`, se houver uma relacionada.

Answer (score 2):

Vejo com bons olhos o uso do Null, ele tem seu cabimento, além da questão da economia de bits, mesmo que seja extremamente pequena, o que me chama a atenção para o uso do null em um campo é com relação a evitar erros e agilizar a inserção de dados.
Por exemplo, numa tabela com várias campos referente a Valores de Creditos:
CréditoCompraX, CréditoCompraY, CréditoCompraW e o usuário adquiriu apenas o crédito da Compra X, então no meu código preciso fazer INSERT INTO apenas para a CreditoCompraX, e no procedimento para verificar o valor da Soma dos Créditos, menos A Soma dos Débitos não ocasiona nenhum problema.
Se não esses campos não estivessem com valor null, no INSERT INTO, teria que fazer menção aos outros campos e constar seus valores como '0'.

Comment: Está um pouco confuso o que você postou, qual a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 0):

Idealmente uma coluna nunca deveria aceitar NULL. A utilidade primária do NULL é para você poder fazer LEFT OUTER JOIN, por exepmlo

```
SELECT * from CLIENTES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PEDIDOS ON CLIENTES.ID = PEDIDOS.ID_CLIENTE 
WHERE PEDIDOS.ID_PEDIDO IS NULL 
GROUP BY CLIENTES.ID
```

Com esta consulta eu descubro os clientes que *não* têm pedidos.