# Como resolver situações especiais de um valor não natural para um domínio?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

A pergunta tem um viés um pouco mais conceitual, por isto vou usar um exemplo genérico simples.

Há casos em que alguma coluna pode estar em situação especial, isto porque uma informação:

- não está disponível,
- é inválida em determinada momento,
- é desconhecida,
- é indeterminada,
- não tem relevância,
- pode estar em uma situação especial que só faça sentido para o [domínio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_domain) específico.

Uma das formas de indicar a situação especial é a [utilização de `null`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101), o que já é questionável se é algo bom ou ruim, embora tudo tem seu mérito em certas circunstâncias. O uso de `null` é um caso claro de escolha de valores especiais não naturais ao domínio da coluna para indicar **uma** situação especial.

Mas você pode necessitar indicar com mais precisão qual é a situação especial, o motivo para o estado atual. Na [pergunta sobre o `null`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101) há uma definição de como soluciona uma situação especial. Mas pode existir mais do que um motivo, e pior, pode ser que novos motivos sejam incluídos no futuro.

Por exemplo, em um controle acadêmico existe uma coluna com notas dos alunos em disciplinas pode não bastar ter uma nota zero. Uma nota zero não o mesmo que ausência de nota. E um `null` pode não ser suficiente já que ele só indica que não há nota. Você precisa saber porque não há nota, já que cada circunstância pode exigir um tratamento diferente. Você precisa saber se a nota:

- ainda não foi dada,
- não existe porque o aluno está dispensado daquela avaliação,
- ele não fez a avaliação (que neste caso é diferente dele ter nota zero).

Eu sei que em alguns casos dá para evitar que existam certos motivos melhorando a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101). Não é esta a questão aqui.

Existem basicamente duas soluções para tratar isto:

1. Documenta que determinados valores sejam considerados como estes motivos (Ex.: valores acima de 10 ou negativos em uma nota são situações especiais discriminadas em cada um destes valores fora da faixa normal, no exemplo `-1` indicaria o motivo `a` citada acima, `-2` o motivo `b` e `-3` para o motivo `c`).
2. Uma coluna auxiliar é usada para indicar o motivo da situação especial (Ex.: nela haverá uma indicação dos motivos a, b ou c citados acima, e é claro, a indicação que a nota é válida e deve ser considerada normalmente, mesmo que seja zero).

Em um domínio com situação especial devemos usar **valores ou colunas auxiliares** para indicar a situação? Ou seja, existe mais **vantagens** em um do que outro? Particularmente prefiro o segundo.

Como lidar com estes casos? Afinal, *queries* podem dar resultados errados sem considerar estes casos. E isto vale para qualquer das duas opções.

Um exemplo típico do problema é o cálculo da média de valores de linhas selecionadas. Mas todos os problemas que envolvem `null`, se aplicam igualmente neste caso. Os sistemas de banco de dados costumam ter uma solução para lidar com o `null`.

*Bônus point: existe uma forma de abstrair (tornar transparente) isto? Ou o usuário (talvez um desenvolvedor) terá que saber desta necessidade e tratar adequadamente em cada query?*

Comment: Deste-me uma volta a cabeça. Acabei por não perceber nada do que querias saber.

Comment: @JorgeB. Você entende do assunto que estou falando? Se você tiver alguma dúvida específica, posso tentar ajudar a clarificar para você.

Comment: Sim entendo, depois leio melhor em casa e digo alguma coisa. Entretanto apago estes comentários.

Comment: Gostaria de entender porque estão considerando a pergunta muito ampla.

Comment: @JorgeB. Se entendi corretamente, o cerne da pergunta é *devemos usar valores ou colunas auxiliares para indicar a situação?* Sendo que "a situação" é que um `NULL` pode representar várias coisas.

Comment: Também não percebi bigown o ampla de mais, nem qualquer outro motivo de fecho. As vezes acho que as pessoas nem sequer leem as perguntas ou então não as percebem e toca a fechar.

Comment: @bfavaretto é isto, mas obviamente quero o motivo e não um simples "este ou aquele". Não quero um capítulo de um livro, não quero múltiplas respostas onde qualquer uma pode estar correta. Uma simples explicação do porque usar uma ou outra opção. É muito parecido com a pergunta sobre o *null* que não foi considerada ampla.

Comment: @JorgeB. é verdade. Se realmente estiver com algum problema, eu estou disposto a melhorá-la. Só preciso entender o que, pois posso ter falhado mas eu me esforcei bastante para não deixá-la com problemas.

Comment: Li várias vezes a pergunta e realmente não entendi. Não tive tempo de comentar o porquê não entendi, por isso votei pra fechar. Agora com as edições, com o exemplo da nota do aluno e a resposta do @Bacco entendi perfeitamente a pergunta. Voto para fechar retirado.

Comment: O uso de _null_ em campos facultativos também se encaixa nas situações especiais? Por exemplo tenho um esquema com tabelas 'Pergunta' e 'Escolha', porém quando o usuário responder ele pode fazer uma resposta livre. Quando a resposta dele for 'livre' a escolha é _null_, ou quando ele escolher uma 'escolha' a resposta livre dele é _null_. Acompanhando o raciocínio da pergunta, eu poderia colocar outro valor no lugar de _null_, por exemplo, 'nao se aplica'... Realmente seria bom se isso fosse abstraído.

Comment: @Earendul Quando você só precisa indicar existe ou ou não, o `null` resolve bem, mesmo em mais uma coluna. Ou seja quando você tem apenas **uma** situação especial para o domínio daquela coluna. O fato de você ter uma situação especial em outra coluna, é um problema separado. Eu entendi que eles são mutualmente exclusivos, mas ainda só existe um motivo para ausência de valor em cada coluna. Não existem dois motivos para a mesma coluna.

Comment: @Earendul Não entender uma pergunta é um excelente motivo para **não votar** para fechar. Outros podem ter (e parecem ter) entendido. Nesses casos, peça esclarecimentos nos comentários. Vote para fechar como "não está claro" quando faltam informações relevantes na pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Entendi, apenas falhei em ser apressado demais, realmente poderia ter esperado por mais detalhes antes de votar. Não se repetirá...

Comment: Acho que essa é uma questão muita ampla e que depende da analise de cada situação e que não terá um certo ou errado

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Todas as situações, como quase tudo que dá margem a este tipo de discussão, tem vantagens e desvantagens. Eis um esboço de algumas das mais comuns que eu me deparo. Notar que estou usando referências bem básicas e usando pseudocódigo por uma questão de clareza apenas:

### O uso do *null*

Para o exemplo evidente, das notas escolares, o *null* é uma boa opção, no sentido de diferenciar uma nota zero de uma nota ainda não lançada no sistema, se a condição especial for apenas a ausência de nota.

O cuidado a se tomar nestes casos é que para se utilizar estes dados, as *queries* vão precisar de condiçoes especiais, como um `WHERE not_null( nota )` para se calcular uma média, por exemplo.

Um erro muito comum é quando o usuário faz uma dessas: `WHERE coluna = null`. Este é um problema muito comum de quem não está acostumado com o conceito de *null*. *Null* não pode ser usado como valor em operações normais sem que o resultado também seja *null*.

Sempre lembrando que semanticamente o *null* é tratado como valor desconhecido, o que nem sempre é o mesmo que valor ausente.

### O uso de "valores mágicos"

Ainda no exemplo da nota, poderiamos fazer diferente: dizer que a nota -1 (ou a nota 100, seja lá o que for convencionado) significa nota não preenchida.

Neste caso continuariamos a ter que nos preocupar com um `WHERE` para fazer todas as operações, e além disso teriamos que ter um destes valores como *default* do campo ao criar a tabela, sob pena de fazer uma grande confusão ao desenvolver o aplicativo.

```
nota INT() DEFAULT 100
```

Considerando que alguns conectores de DB tem problemas ao retornar o *null*, uma possível vantagem do uso de valores mágicos é a facilidade de tratar estas condições no lado do aplicativo.

Uma outra vantagem desta solução é que os valores mágicos podem ser utilizados para indicar mais de uma situação, e não apenas um valor especial (o que já foi dito no *edit* da pergunta, mas vale relembrar). Por exemplo, 100 é "aguardando", 101 é "dispensado", 102 é "trabalho substitutivo" e assim por diante.

### Será que não é caso de *enum*?

Ainda pegando o exemplo das notas, uma saída muito similar a dos "valores mágicos" consta em "dar nome" para estes valores, definindo o campo desta forma:

```
nota ENUM( '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','aguardando','dispensado')
```

As vantagens são a legibilidade dos dados ao se analisar e editar o DB com ferramentas nativas, e o fato dos valores do *enum* ainda poderem ser usados para médias e somas, desde que criados na ordem correta.

A desvantagem é a mesma dos valores mágicos, a necessidade de condições para se obter valores agregados, para que se considere apenas os valores de 0 a 10. Talvez até seja necessária alguma conversão de tipos nos agregadores, e tamém pode haver um offset entre a nota zero e o valor do enum, dependendo do SGBD e do valor interno do ítem inicial.

### O uso de colunas extras

Este caso provavelmente só deve ser usado quando a separação de valores especiais e "convencionais" puder ajudar de fato as *queries* ou a aplicação de alguma forma. Mais raramente, em casos em que não é aceitável alguma das possibilidades mencionadas anteriormente, seja por performance ou limitação das tecnologias sendo usadas.

Se você tem muitas exceções, a coluna extra indexada pode acelerar a query, retornando apenas o que é necessário, agilizando, por exemplo o uso de funções agregadoras como `SUM()` e `AVG()`.

### Coleções de dados além da estrutura da tabela

Vamos esquecer as notas escolares agora, isto é para dados completamente diferentes. Se você enfrentar situações em que a necessidade dos valores especiais é grande, e que poderiam ocorrer em diversas coluna nos modelos propostos anteriormente, pode até pensar em vez disso em usar uma coluna especial.

Por exemplo, uma coluna de metadados, onde você pudesse armazenar coleções textualmente, como "colação de grau:12/03/1960, casamento:21/05/1967, falecimento:03/08/2011" no mesmo campo. Lembrando que este caso faz mais sentido em SGDBs relacionais.

O problema aqui é que estes dados são quase que *improcessáveis* fora da aplicação principal.

Lembrando sempre que este caso é para situações bem específicas apenas, só mencionei como complemento. Provavelmente o desenvolvedor vai perceber quando precisar de uma saída deste tipo.

Answer (score 9):

A resposta descrevendo a decisão do procedimento ideal dependerá de dois fatores:

- Quão resistente o seu modelo é em relação a mudanças, e
- Quão resistente a mudanças são os processos dependentes.

Vamos a uma simulação. No caso mencionado, podemos assumir um modelo como este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que se traduz da seguinte maneira:

> O domínio onde é expressa a nota de um dado aluno em uma dada matéria.

Temos agora um uma necessidade de *overload* desse domínio:

> Como expressar a razão pela qual um dado aluno não possui nota em uma dada matéria?

O que implica em:

> Como expressar uma ausência de nota?

É aí que o valor `Null` pode ser importante, servindo como um marcador que indica que o contexto não se aplica ao domínio esperado.:

> Temos uma situação onde não posso expressar uma nota, mas não é minha responsabilidade descrever a razão. Sua princesa está em outro castelo.

É neste momento que as duas perguntas acima devem ser avaliadas.

### Caso tanto o modelo quanto os processos sejam flexíveis

O recomendado é continuar mantendo o seu modelo físico como uma expressão do modelo lógico (que obviamente requer o domínio *Razão pela qual o aluno não possui nota*) e refatorar tanto o modelo quanto os processos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Caso seu modelo seja flexível, porém os processos não

Você pode implementar o novo domínio, mantendo a interface esperada pelos processos não-refatorados.

Uma possibilidade é a alteração do nome da tabela original (que será consumida pelos novos processos que sabem da presença de um novo domínio) e a criação de uma `view` com o mesmo nome da tabela antiga (que servirá para alimentar os processos legados):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é um processo que atente a qualquer método de leitura; vários SGBDs permitem também a manipulação inferida de dados por uma view (como [MS SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx) e [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/view-updatability.html), por exemplo), permitindo assim que métodos `UPDATE`, `INSERT` e `DELETE` sejam executados via referência.

### Caso tanto o modelo quanto os processos sejam rígidos

A opção é criar o domínio em um repositório à parte (outro modelo, ou diretamente no código via enumeração, coleções estáticas ou similares).

Tenha sempre em mente que quanto mais próximo seu modelo de dados for dos domínios que ele procura expressar, melhor; isso se traduz em menores prazos para manutenção, mapeamento de processos e expansão do modelo.

Soluções envolvendo domínios fora de escopo ('tabelas' no código ou similares) ofuscam aspectos do modelo e tendem a *Spaghettizar* a solução.