# A seguinte modelagem de banco de dados é nóia da minha cabeça?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, null

Criei essa modelagem (apenas uma ideia), de forma a não ter campos nulos/brancos.

Não revisei por completo. Podem haver campos que ficariam em branco. A tabela matriz foi a Entidades e através das necessidades de não haver campos em branco, as outras surgiram.

De certo devem haver campos desnecessários em algumas tabelas, como quem cadastrou/atualizou e quando essas acoes ocorreram. Gostaria que alguém que entenda de modelagem se tem cabimento minha ideia e onde isso que eu fiz me prejudicaria no desenvolvimento. Obrigado.

[image: Dúvida em ideia de modelagem]

Comment: Não sei se vai garantir inexistência de brancos, mas não parece haver necessidade de nulos. Não sei se você tem um problema específico aí pra resolver. Pra mim parece tudo ok. Mas só olhando o modelo não dá para garantir que está tudo correto. Dizer se prejudicaria é mais complicado. Não ter nulos é algo interessante, mas não pode ser um objetivo em si. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fora a nomenclatura adotada que eu não gosto, mas não é um problema, não parece ter erros dentro do requerimento da pergunta. Mas se não vai prejudicar em nada é mais complicado dizer, não sei como será usado.

Não dá para garantir só por isso que não haverá brancos, nem mesmo nulos, mas o modelo parece, até onde dá para entender, que ajuda evitar que existam nulos.

O que é uma boa, mas [não se deve perseguir a todo custo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/101).

O que eu achei estranho é a tabela de endereço que só pode ter um item por entidade. Ou seria interessante colocar o endereço na tabela principal, já que só tem um, ou se isto está errado, deveria tirar a coluna da tabela `TEntidade` que relaciona o endereço e colocar uma coluna em `TEndereco` que relacione com a entidade, assim permitirá vários endereços, que eu acho que é a intenção.

Tem tabela que parece sobrar, por exemplo `TIE`. Não vejo porque isso existe. Mas pode ter um motivo que não percebi.

Algumas coisas parecem soltas. Não vejo vínculos reais com `TEntidadesTipos`. Pode ser só um problema de nome de coluna, mas também não vejo vínculo com `TSituacoes`.

Posso ter deixado passar alguma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: hahah realmente essa nomenclatura, particularmente, me dá arrepios srr

Answer (score 1):

Nomenclatura eh igual a escova de dentes neh pessoal? rs. Mas se houver um padrão gostaria de ler sobre.

Maniero

A ideia da tabela `TENDERECOS` eh não ter duplicados. Escritos de forma incorreta existirão, mas sempre haverão pessoas que corrigirão pra forma correta. Mas se escreverem Uashinton Soares no lugar de Washington Soares? Buscaremos pelo CEP ou via programação incluímos endereços que constem a segunda parte do nome ou amarre pelos CEPs do estado, com uma opção de mostrar todos.

A tabela `TIE`, inscrição estadual, não sei se todos os estados tem, 
mas já vi CNPJs que não tem. Eu, como MEI, não tenho.

Ela existe pra não deixar campo branco/nulo em `TPJ`;

Acho que RG também deveria fazer de uma tabela a parte, pois eh um documento secundário.

`TENTIDADESTIPOS` são os tipos de entidades (fornecedor, cliente, consumidor, funcionário, terceirizado, etc); 
`TSITUACOES` eh por conta da situação de uma entidade, pedido, compra.. pode estar ativa, bloqueada, cancelada, 
pendente, fechada, aberta, em transito, entregue... essas coisas.

Comment: Existe um padrão chamado [EAV (Entity Attribute Value)](https://inviqa.com/blog/2010/10/21/the-eav-data-model).

Comment: [EAV - Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)

Comment: O link que você passou não se refere a uma nomenclatura de entidades/atributos e sim uma forma de estruturar as tabelas/atributos/valores, que eh interessante (e confuso). (y)

Comment: Na verdade é um anti-pattern, mas existe dentro dessa estrutura, um padrão de nomenclatura, [veja aqui](http://blog.fabianobento.com.br/2011/09/padroes-para-nomenclatura-em-um-banco-de-dados/) e [aqui outro exemplo](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/253/padroes-de-nomenclaturas-guia-de-consulta-rapida.aspx)