# Contrução de tabelas SQL - usar ou não campos com Not Null?

Tags: sql, null

Estou com uma duvida, referente a construção de tabelas e a utilização de campo `Not Null`.

Sei que para campos de `Primary Key`, é necessário ele ser `Not Null`, porem nos demais campos, qual a necessidade de utilizar `Not Null`? pelo que entendo se um campo for setado como `Not Null`, ele não aceitara valores nulos, então caso, a minha aplicação na hora de realizar o `insert`, não for informado um determinado campo que esteja setado como `Not Null`, teremos ai uma Exceção?

Se um campo estiver setado como `Not Null`, fico na obrigatoriedade de sempre mencionar ele na hora do `insert`?

Quando devo utilizar campos `Not Null`?

Comment: [Quando devemos permitir que uma coluna de uma tabela de um banco de dados aceite NULL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/91)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Qual a necessidade de utilizar Not Null?

Você deve criar uma coluna como `Not Null` quando ver a necessidade de que aquele campo tem que ser preenchido no momento do insert. Por exemplo, imagine uma tabela de endereço um campo crucial é o nome da RUA e o CEP esses campos são muito importante serem informados, afinal não adiantaria nada você ter o número da rua sem sabe o NOME ou o CEP.

Algumas colunas em tabelas podem ter seu valor como null pelo fato de existir ou não um dado para aquele determinado objeto.

Um bom exemplo disso é o campo de telefone (celular), algumas pessoas podem não ter um número de telefone para informa no momento do cadastro e outras pessoas terão, nesse caso o campo com o `Default null` seria muito bom.

> Senão for informado um determinado campo que esteja setado como Not
>   Null, teremos ai uma Exceção?

Sim, se você tenta fazer um `insert` ou `updade` numa coluna sendo `not null` vai receber uma exceção.

***Não é possível inserir o valor NULL na coluna 'Nome', tabela
 'Exemplos.dbo.Tabela'; a coluna não permite nulos. Falha em INSERT.***

> Se um campo estiver setado como Not Null, fico na obrigatoriedade de
>   sempre mencionar ele na hora do insert?

Sim, se não o erro acima será apresentado.

> Quando devo utilizar campos Not Null?

Em casos onde o valor do campo tem que existir (IDs como chave primaria) ou campos de devem ser obrigatório como o nome de usuário em uma tabela de usuário, mas isso depende muito da regra de negócio de sua aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

No caso se seu campo for do tipo "Not Null" você deve sempre atribuir um valor à ele antes de salvar, nem que seja um valor vazio somente as aspas '' no caso de caracteres. Porém há também uma utilização desta funcionalidade, que eu particularmente utilizo muito, se tenho um campo "bool" que seja para gravar um resposta do usuário, caso este campo ainda esteja no banco como "null" sabemos que ainda não foi tomada uma resposta válida para aquela questão. caso seja verdadeiro ou falso sabemos que foi respondida.
Mesma coisa vale para datas, sendo a data null, podemos considerar que um pagamento ainda não foi realizado, e quando preenchida, este foi pago.

Comment: Isso. Para pagamentos não realizados eu deixo o campo Default Null. No SELECT filtro os campos que contenham NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Olá.

Sempre tenho esse problema do valor default no campo. Primeiro sempre deixava com Default Null, Se o usuário preenchesse ou não a tabela aceitaria. Quando começava o relacionamento com outras tabelas no aplicativo é que via os problemas. Registros que tinham o campos DateTime NULL não eram listados ou até outras consultas que necessitam comparar valores. Como o NULL é desconhecido a consulta ignorava-o no SELECT.

Para permitir que o usuário não precisasse preencher alguns campos, passei a usar um valor Default padrão, no caso de datas CURRENT_DATE, chaves estrangeiras Default '0' ou 'Nenhum selecionado', booleanos Default '0', e por aí vai.

Sempre que um campo for parte de uma consulta prefiro deixá-lo  NOT NULL.

Espero ter contribuído.

Answer (score 2):

"... **é necessario ele ser Not Null, porem nos demais campos, qual a necessidade de utilizar Not Null?** ..."

Essa nececidade vai depender de o campo ser referenciado em alguma relação que vc fizer na camada do DB, caso contrario, se for um campo que necessite obrigatoriamente ter um valor para alguma referencia feita com esse campo na camada ou camadas mais superiores ao DB. Sendo assim a escolha para deixar um campo como "*NOT NULL*" fica a critério do desenho da aplicação.

Em alguns casos, como no uso de relações nas camadas superiores as da camada do DB, o projetista pode deixar um campo setado com um valor "*DEFAULT {value}*" caso ele precise do valor desse campo para uma referencia no código do aplicativo.

Mas, se a camada do DB, que não pelo fato de ser a primeira camada de uma aplicação é a mais importante, pois o projetista pode desenhar quase todo o software nessa camada, que uma vez estando funcionando bem redondinha, é realmente a camada que vai realizar todo o trabalho do processamento dos dados do aplicativo, assim, vai abranger na aplicação, inumeros aspectos positivos nos quesitos **tráfico, velocidade, usabilidade e segurança**, uma vez que o processamento da massa de dados está quase que todo sendo feito pelas relações corretas no database, a aplicação somente tem de se preocupar com o "cara-a-cara usuario-dados" o que facilita consideravelmente o desenvolvimento, a usabilidade, a velocidade de processamento e consequentemente a segurança da aplicação.

Sendo assim, todos os campos que forem referenciados precisam estar ou setados como "NOT NULL" ou setados com um valor "DEFAULT {value}".

Eu em alguns caso prefiro fazer essa verificacao nas camadas mais superiores do aplicativo.

Mas por exemplo: 
suponhamos que num aplicativo voce tenha definido as relações corretas no database, logicamente você vai depender de horas de trabalho para desenhar e formatar as tabelas no database para atender aos criterios do desenho do seu aplicativo, ora, essas horas que voce vai gastar desenhando bem o database, são as horas que voce vai ganhar no desenvolvimento da UI do aplicativo quando o cliente já vai estar com certeza te "xutando o saco, kkkkkkkkk".

espero que ajude.

Saúde e Paz!