# Como mostrar numa consulta registros que não tem um dado referenciado

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho 3 tabelas:

**Pessoa**

```
CREATE TABLE Pessoa (
    ID_Pessoa INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    ID_Telefone INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Telefone (ID_Telefone),
    Nome_PSOA VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CPF_PSOA CHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    RG_PSOA VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Classe_PSOA VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Cadastro_Pendente_PSOA BIT 
);
```

**Funcionario**

```
CREATE TABLE Funcionario (
    ID_Funcionario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    ID_Pessoa INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pessoa (ID_Pessoa) NOT NULL,
    ID_Cargo INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cargo (ID_Cargo),
    Email_FUNC VARCHAR(50),
    Ramal_FUNC VARCHAR(4),
    Horario_Trabalho_FUNC VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Escala_FUNC VARCHAR(25),
    Permitir_Visitas_FUNC BIT,
    Descricao_FUNC VARCHAR(200) 
);
```

**Cargo**

```
CREATE TABLE Cargo (
    ID_Cargo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    ID_Departamento INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Departamento (ID_Departamento) NOT NULL,
    Nome_CRGO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Descricao_CRGO VARCHAR(200)
);
```

Na minha aplicação tenho uma consulta que retorna os seguintes dados (respectivamente):
*ID_Pessoa - ID_Funcionario - Nome_PSOA - Nome_CRGO - RG_PSOA - CPF_PSOA*

A questão é a seguinte : Quando eu removo um cargo do sistema eu seto **`NULL`** no `ID_Cargo` todos os registros de `Funcionario` que tem aquele cargo para que eu possa excluí-lo sem problemas de integridade referencial. Porém, quando a consulta é executada, o `DataGridView` me retorna apenas os registros que tem um `ID_Cargo` diferente de nulo. Meu objetivo é, no campo **`Nome_CRGO`** de todos os registros com o `ID_Cargo = NULL`, não mostrar nada, mas fazer com que os mesmos apareçam na consulta.

Consulta que não deu certo :

```
SELECT TOP 20 dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa AS 'ID', 
    ID_Funcionario AS 'ID do Funcionário', 
    Nome_PSOA AS 'Nome', 
    Nome_CRGO AS 'Cargo', 
    RG_PSOA AS 'RG', 
    CPF_PSOA AS 'CPF'
FROM dbo.Pessoa, 
    dbo.Funcionario, 
    dbo.Cargo 
WHERE dbo.Funcionario.ID_Pessoa = dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa 
    AND (
         dbo.Cargo.ID_Cargo = dbo.Funcionario.ID_Cargo 
         OR dbo.Funcionario.ID_Cargo = NULL
        ) 
ORDER BY dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa DESC
```

Comment: faz o mesmo sql só que com left outer join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (...) Quando a consulta é executada, o `DataGridView` me retorna apenas os registros que tem um `ID_Cargo` diferente de nulo

Isso acontece devido ao fato de você ter definido uma expressão que nunca será verdadeira no que seria a declaração de faculdade de existência do cargo. Implícitamente, você acabou definindo um `INNER JOIN` entre as 3 tabelas.

Veja:

```
...
dbo.Funcionario.ID_Pessoa = dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa // INNER JOIN entre funcionario e pessoa
     AND (
          dbo.Cargo.ID_Cargo = dbo.Funcionario.ID_Cargo // Implicitamente INNER JOIN entre cargo e funcionario
          OR dbo.Funcionario.ID_Cargo = NULL // Nunca será verdadeiro
         )
```

Isso acontece porque o `null` se comporta mais como um 'estado' do que como um valor.

**[Há uma pergunta que aqui mesmo no SOpt que detalha mais a questão do NULL no banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2296/quando-devemos-permitir-que-uma-coluna-de-uma-tabela-de-um-banco-de-dados-aceite)**.

Em resumo, no SQL, considerando que a coluna `ID_Cargo` esteja como `null`, o resultado da expressão `ID_cargo = NULL` é `Falso` assim como a expressão `ID_cargo <> NULL` também o é. A forma correta da comparação nesse caso seria `ID_cargo IS NULL`. Assim retornaria `Verdadeiro`, como esperado.

Particularmente, prefiro separar o que é critério de junção de tabelas (as cláusulas `JOIN` declaradas no `FROM`) do que é condição de seleção (essas declaradas no `WHERE`). Como [proposto por Rovann Linhalis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304167/como-mostrar-numa-consulta-registros-que-n%c3%a3o-tem-um-dado-referenciado#comment617445_304167), você poderia também fazer um `LEFT OUTER JOIN` explícitamente na consulta.

Assim:

```
SELECT TOP 20 dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa AS 'ID', 
    ID_Funcionario AS 'ID do Funcionário', 
    Nome_PSOA AS 'Nome', 
    Nome_CRGO AS 'Cargo', 
    RG_PSOA AS 'RG', 
    CPF_PSOA AS 'CPF'
FROM dbo.Pessoa 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Funcionario ON dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa = dbo.Funcionario.ID_Pessoa 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Cargo ON dbo.Funcionario.ID_Cargo = dbo.Cargo.ID_Cargo
ORDER BY dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa DESC
```

Para esse exemplo específico, a consulta dispensa o uso do `WHERE` pois todas as condições referem-se somente aos critérios de junção das tabelas.