# Select com colunas informando dados incorretos

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, select

Olá

Estou com mais um problema referente a uma busca no banco de dados.
Quero fazer um SELECT que busque informações como cod.empresa, razaosocial, ano e valores(somados).
A principio, a busca das informações sem a razão social estão corretas, porém quando adicionei a tabela que contem a razão social deu problema, pois está chegando informações repetidas, tirando a razão social.

Existe a possibilidade de contornar essa situação?
pois os códigos das empresas não estão de acordo com as razões sociais.

segue abaixo a query:

```
SELECT
    i.empresa,
    j.razaosocial,
    i.exercicio,
    (
        CASE
        WHEN c.lucrocontabil = 0 THEN
            c.lucrosimples
        WHEN c.lucrosimples = 0 THEN
            c.lucrocontabil
        END
    ) AS lucro
FROM
    empresas j,
    informessocios i
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        sum(COALESCE(lucrocontabil, 0)) AS lucrocontabil,
        sum(COALESCE(lucrosimples, 0)) AS lucrosimples,
        empresa,
        exercicio
    FROM
        informessocios
    WHERE
        exercicio = 2017
    AND (
        lucrocontabil > 0
        OR lucrosimples > 0
    )
    GROUP BY
        empresa,
        exercicio,
        lucrocontabil,
        lucrosimples
) c ON c.empresa = i.empresa
AND c.exercicio = i.exercicio
WHERE
    c.exercicio = 2017
GROUP BY
    i.empresa,
    i.exercicio,
    lucro,
    j.razaosocial
ORDER BY
    i.empresa
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notem que o código das empresas e valores estão iguais porém a razão social não.

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda!

Segue a estrutura das tabelas:

[Tabela] informessocios

```
CREATE TABLE public.informessocios(

empresa VarChar(6) With Comp NOT NULL 3 [] True
exercicio Long NOT NULL 3 [] True
lucrocontabil Double NULL 3 [] False
lucrosimples Double NULL 3 [] False
CONSTRAINT pk_informessocios PRIMARY KEY (empresa, exercicio, socio)
)
```

[Tabela] empresas

```
CREATE TABLE public.empresas(

empresa VarChar(6) With Comp NOT NULL 3 [] True
razaosocial VarChar(50) With Comp NULL 3 [] False
CONSTRAINT pk_empresas PRIMARY KEY (empresa, exercicio)
)
```

Comment: não sei se precisa dizer mas acho que seu banco tá meio _zoado_.. ta correto o mesmo código com nomes diferentes? se trocar `i.empresa` por `j.empresa` altera algo??

Comment: Infelizmente sim, pois aqui na empresa o banco de dados é bagunçado, pois são inúmeras tabelas ou seja, tive que fazer uma busca nas tabelas para que pudesse colher o resultado necessário.

Comment: e como você vai definir qual nome usar? o primeiro (pelo id)? o menor (qtd de caracteres)?

Comment: Desculpa a ignorância, não entendi muito bem a pergunta...

Comment: supondo que `010011` tenha 3 nomes diferentes (tipo "_abc_", "_abc 2_" e "_abc 3_"), qual vai ser o critério pra escolher op1, op2 ou op3? seria, por exemplo, o primeiro cadastrado na base??

Comment: Sim, cadastrado pelo primeiro da base.

Comment: Que tal substituir a terceira linha por `min(j.razaosocial) as razaosocial,` e remover o `j.razaosocial` do GROUP BY lá no final? Isso pega a primeira razão social que aparecer e boa, notando que pode não ser necessariamente a primeira razão social que foi cadastrada na base para aquela empresa.

Comment: Desculpa a demora, tive outros afazeres e não tive como focar nessa query.
Antes de tudo, agradeço a ajuda. Pois bem, 'nunks', eu fiz como você falou, porém ele reduziu as informações para 172 rows (correto), porém a razão social ficou igual para todas as empresas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salve rapaziada, mais uma vez agradeço a vocês por me ajuda.
Agora trago a solução do problema.
Refiz a query e usei algumas condições no C#. Agora o programa está correto. Segue a solução:

QUERY:

SELECT
    e.empresa, 
    e.razaosocial, 
    i.exercicio,
    (
        CASE
        WHEN i.lucrocontabil=0 THEN 
            i.lucrosimples 
        WHEN i.lucrosimples=0 THEN 
            i.lucrocontabil end
        ) as lucro
FROM 
    empresas e
JOIN 
    informessocios i 
    ON e.empresa=i.empresa 
    AND e.exercicio=2017
    WHERE i.exercicio = 2017
    AND (i.lucrocontabil > 0 
    OR i.lucrosimples > 0)
GROUP BY e.empresa, 
     e.razaosocial, 
     i.exercicio, 
     i.lucrocontabil, 
     i.lucrosimples
ORDER BY 
e.empresa

C#

/* Faz uma varredura para verificação de empresas iguais e faz a soma dos valores*/
                decimal valor = 0;

```
            for (int i = 0; i < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; j++)
                {
                    if (RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() && i != j && j != i)
                    {                            
                        valor = decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                        RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = valor;
                        RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                    }

                }
            }
```

/*Faz uma 2ª Varredura para verificação de empresas iguais, pois à alguns itens que repetem por mais de 3 vezes*/
                for (int i = 0; i < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < RelatorioContabilDataGridView.RowCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString() && i != j && j != i)
                        {
                            valor = decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) + decimal.Parse(RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                            RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = valor;
                            RelatorioContabilDataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                        }
                    }
                }

Comment: achei a origem do seu problema, em breve tento te ajudar aqui. Isso no C# está bem errado.... rsrs... coloque para nós a estrutura das suas tabelas por favor

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, hahaha, infelizmente não posso colocar as informações da estrutura do banco de dados, pois pertence a empresa =/

Comment: nao precisa das informações sensíveis cara... só as que vão sair na query... com dados fictícios tambem. Pela query, já dá pra saber algumas coisas... tipo... tabela `informesocios` tem as colunas `empresa`, `exercicio`, ... mas é ruim ficar analizando a query e imaginando a estrutura das tabelas rs, só pra facilitar o trabalho mesmo. Tipo uma pergunta com essas informações, ajuda muito: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304167/69359

Comment: Entendi, as tabelas aqui, são imensas.
Por exemplo, a tabela `empresas` possui umas 100 colunas (sem brincadeira),
Vou mandar apenas com os dados que são utilizados.

Comment: rsrs sei como, mas o que interessa são só as colunas que vão ser utilizadas na query

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente o problema está neste trecho da query:

```
FROM
    empresas j,
    informessocios i
```

Parece que vc está misturado joins explícitos com implícitos.
Além disso nunca use campos como "nome" ou "código" como chaves de joins o correto é usar um ID único.

De resto fica difícil dar uma solução sem conhecer a modelagem de sua base, como essas tabelas se relacionam ou mesmo se vc tem dados duplicados mesmo.

Comment: Entendi, infelizmente o banco de dados é da empresa, quando cheguei já está assim hehe.
Estou meio que "rebolando" para encontrar as informações necessárias.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o código abaixo:

```
SELECT
    i.empresa,
    (SELECT top 1 j1.razaosocial from empresas j1 where j.id= j1.id) as j.razaosocial,
    i.exercicio,
    (
        CASE
        WHEN c.lucrocontabil = 0 THEN
            c.lucrosimples
        WHEN c.lucrosimples = 0 THEN
            c.lucrocontabil
        END
    ) AS lucro
FROM
    empresas j,
    informessocios i
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        sum(COALESCE(lucrocontabil, 0)) AS lucrocontabil,
        sum(COALESCE(lucrosimples, 0)) AS lucrosimples,
        empresa,
        exercicio
    FROM
        informessocios
    WHERE
        exercicio = 2017
    AND (
        lucrocontabil > 0
        OR lucrosimples > 0
    )
    GROUP BY
        empresa,
        exercicio,
        lucrocontabil,
        lucrosimples
) c ON c.empresa = i.empresa
AND c.exercicio = i.exercicio
WHERE
    c.exercicio = 2017
GROUP BY
    i.empresa,
    i.exercicio,
    lucro,
    j.razaosocial
ORDER BY
    i.empresa
```

A ideia do `(SELECT top 1 j1.razaosocial from empresas j1 where j.empresa = j1.empresa)` é que você tenha apenas o primeiro nome retornado.

Comment: Tentei utilizar o codigo, porém ele deu erro no inicio:

LINE 3:     (SELECT top 1 j1.razaosocial from empresas j1 where j.em...
                        ^

Tentei manipular, porém continuou com erro.

Comment: então foi o `order by`.. removi lá, vê se resolveu.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou...
LINE 3:     (SELECT top 1 j1.razaosocial from empresas j1 where j.em...
                        ^

Comment: podes validar a condição no `where`? o campo de código da empresa seria `empresa` (como na `informessocios`) ou `id`? Se for `id`, precisamos alterar pra `(SELECT top 1 j1.razaosocial from empresas j1 where j.id = j1.id)` (entende?!)

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar fazer desse jeito.

Comment: Tentei de diversas formas, porém não deu certo.
Existe muitas colunas nas tabelas e está afetando o resultado dos selects.
Eu optei por não mostrar a razão social.

Comment: ixi, agora lascô =/

Comment: Mas tranquilo.
Agradeço muito a sua ajuda.
Obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @Andre mas oh, se não resolveu, não precisa marcar como aceita, vai que alguém tem a solução.. ;)

Comment: Entendi haha, valeu pela dica!!

Answer (score 0):

André,
Existe um comando no sql chama row_number, ele faz uma lista de acordo com os parametro.

Acesse o link abaixo e veja o exemplo.
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

Eu não sei como está a sua base, acredito que por não tem uma centralização dos dados, você esteja tendo um pouco de dificuldade. Acredito que seria legal, você fazer um plano de normalização dos dados.

A principio seria usar o comando abaixo

ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY "nome_da_Empresa" ORDER BY "data_de_Cadastro_mais_antiga")

Um forte abs

Comment: Edmilson, eu vou seguir a sua dica.
Assim que eu tiver um posicionamento, eu posto aqui.

Obrigado man.