# Qual utilidade de declarar uma coluna como Char(0)?

Tags: mysql, tipagem

Eu sei que `CHAR(0)` não é definido no ANSI SQL, mas no MySQL é possível definir uma coluna com especificação deste tipo de dados.

Qual seria o uso/utilidade de tal coluna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É para manter a coluna existente no modelo sem ocupar espaço real de dados.

Algumas aplicações podem querer acessar uma coluna que não faz mais sentido existir no DB ou que ainda não é hora de usá-la de fato. Então para não quebrar a aplicação você mantém a coluna existente, o que será incluída em requisições, inclusive quando faz um `select * from` ela estará lá, mesmo sem dado algum real.

O MySQL tende ser mais permissivo e eu acho essa permissividade específica boa porque ela é útil em casos assim. Só não é para abusar. Tende a ser mais útil quando o banco de dados acaba funcionando como uma API do sistema, o que não costuma ser uma boa escolha.

Ainda é possível usar para indicar a nulidade de um valor ou não (e só isso é indicado, mais nada). Porque todas colunas são controladas com um bit, então ela ocupará o espaço de 1 bit, que pode mudar o tamanho da linha ou não dependendo da composição das outras colunas. Pode ver mais sobre isso em [resposta do Bacco sobre nulidade em banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2297/101).

Já vi gente usando isso para ter um dado booleano menor que o existente que ocupa 1 byte, mas é abuso, e pode ter dificuldades no futuro por causa disso, eu não arriscaria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: ocupará apenas um bit e só poderá receber 2 valores: NULL ou '' (a string vazia)